# StAX EventFilter StackOverflowError

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have this EventFilter implementation that's supposed to filter `<InterestingElement>` start element events:

```
class InterestingElementFilter implements EventFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(XMLEvent event)
    {
        if (event.isStartElement()) {
            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            String name = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
            if (name.equals("InterestingElement")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I create a filtered reader:

```
XMLEventReader interestingElementReader = xmlInputFactory.createFilteredReader(xmlEventReader, new InterestingElementFilter());
```

When calling

```
startElementReader.peek();
```

I get this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.seekCloseOfStartTag(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.peek(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.stream.util.EventReaderDelegate.peek(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.EventFilterSupport.peek(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.EventFilterSupport.peek(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.EventFilterSupport.peek(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.EventFilterSupport.peek(Unknown Source)
```

I would appreciate if someone have a clue on what the problem is.

Comment: what did you finally figure out on this?  If it's still a mystery, you might want to show more of the stack - or summarize, e.g., ... "followed by 2000 more EventFilterSupport.peek()" calls.  It's not clear where the over-recursion is from the short excerpt.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to reproduce your issue, the following based on your description works for me.  Have I missed something from your question?:

**InterestingElementFilter**

```
import javax.xml.stream.EventFilter;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

class InterestingElementFilter implements EventFilter {

    public boolean accept(XMLEvent event)
    {
        if (event.isStartElement()) {
            StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
            String name = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
            if (name.equals("InterestingElement")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream("input.xml"));
        InterestingElementFilter filter = new InterestingElementFilter();
        XMLEventReader interestingElementReader = xmlInputFactory.createFilteredReader(xmlEventReader, filter);

        while(interestingElementReader.hasNext()) {
            XMLEvent xmlEvent = interestingElementReader.peek();
            if(xmlEvent.isStartElement()) {
                System.out.println(xmlEvent.asStartElement().getName());
            }
            interestingElementReader.next();
        }
    }

}
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <InterestingElement>
        <child>Hello World</child>
    </InterestingElement>
</root>
```

Comment: I believe you missed the fact that I'm working with a slightly bigger file, say, from some hundred Mb to a couple Gb.

Comment: @adrianboimvaser - Does your filter work on smaller documents (your question does not mention file size)?

Comment: Yes, it does. Sorry for not mentioning it.